# Error on schema update Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cmd, jobeet

When I try to update the schema using this command :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get these errors :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\jobeet>php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\jobeet\app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to
 open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobeet\app\console on
 line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\jobeet\app
/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\jo
beet\app\console on line 10
```

Can you help me ? Why I get this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a composer install will create the missing file :

```
php composer.phar install
```

then you will be able to run the command again

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```